# API Gateway returning 502 error with a certain file size

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway

We are using S3 and Amazon API Gateway.  I'm getting 502 errors when testing my API in AWS.  On my local machine I always get the file as expected.

I created the following `TestApiController` which I make a simple HTTP GET request from a UI:

```
    [HttpGet("file/{type}")]
    public IActionResult GetFile(string type)
    {
        var filePath =  _env.ContentRootPath + "/Files/my-small.fileType"; // ~5.5MB

        if (type == "big"){
            filePath = _env.ContentRootPath + "/Files/my-big.fileType";// ~6.6MB
        }else if(type == "slowbig") {
            Thread.Sleep(11000);
            filePath = _env.ContentRootPath + "/Files/my-big.fileType";
        }

        var xml = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filePath);

        return File(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(xml), "text/xml", "hardcodedoutput.fileType");
    }
```

**In the test server AWS environment**

if `type == big OR type == slowbig`

> ERROR:  HTTP 502.  Response:  `{"message": "Internal server error"}`

else

> HTTP 200.  I get the file `hardcodedoutput.fileType` as a download in my browser as expected.

**On my Local development machine when running the API:**

if `type == big OR type == slowbig OR type == small`

> HTTP 200.  I get the file `hardcodedoutput.fileType` as a download in my browser as expected.

Answer (score 2):

A 502 can indicate a timeout issue.  The server is taking longer than expected. Check the http server log for errors. If you see none, increase the timeout on the gateway.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [AWS docs:](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html)

> **AWS Lambda Limits**
>
> The following limits apply to function configuration, deployments, and
>   execution. They cannot be changed.
>
> [Invocation payload](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-invocation.html) (request and response)
>
> 6 MB (synchronous)
>
> 256 KB (asynchronous)

This data (albeit a cryptic error) lines up perfectly w/ my experience.  > 6MB files don't work.